# CSS style sheet not found

Tags: html, css

I spent the last hour figuring out why my style sheet is working.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMGyQ.jpg)

I tried every possible way, but none of it works.

It just shows error 404 when I check it in the developer mode of my browser.

I tried

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href=".../style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I also placed the CSS file in the same file as my *header.php* file.

Comment: ^ Well, there is also a `style.css` in the folder `inc`

Comment: ../css/style.css

Comment: It's all relative to your filesystem and where you're calling this, e.g. `inc/style.css` called from `pages/mods/user/index.html` would need a different path from `inc/header.html`

Comment: Unfortunately none of this does work.

Comment: Re *"...why my style sheet is working..."*: Don't you mean *"...why my style sheet is* ***not*** *working..."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the css file is a relative path from **the file that's called from the browser**, and that's most likely not `header.php`.

If you start the path with a `/` it's considered relative to the webroot, so you probably want `/css/style.css`. Note that you cannot go up (using `../`) from the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

**../** is meant to go back a folder, so if my folder layout is

Root

- css

  - style.css
- includes

  - header.php

I have to go down a folder and enter the *css* folder like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Comment: URLs are relative to the URL of the HTML document, not the location of the include file on the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using many link tags to integrate the CSS file in your HTML file. You should use one tag and it would be a relative path like the following `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`